# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'unread' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ionic3, angularfire2

I keep getting the error below when the page first loads, but I can just exit out of it and everything keeps working as expected.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'unread' 
of undefined
at listing-element.ts:34
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at SafeSubscriber._next (listing-element.ts:33)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
```

I am currently using Angular 4.4.3, Ionic-Angular 3.9.2, AngularFire2 5.0.0.

When I run the code below, everything works as expected, but I can't seem to get rid of the `Cannot read property 'unread'` error that pops up on init no matter how many if statements I wrap the offending bit of code in. It's like I have Schrodinger's Observable; I am simultaneously getting the data I am expecting, yet it's coming back undefined. I realize it's due to the async nature of Observables, but I did not have any issues with this until my team switched our database to Google Firestore and therefore had to upgrade AngularFire 2.

We're having similar issues with our pipes and HTML. For our HTML, usually wrapping the code within an `<div *ngIf="thread">` will work, so that it will only appear once we get the listing data. However, wrapping the TypeScript within something like `if (threads.length > 0 && threads)` does nothing, as the data still console logs with the expected result.

```
    //listing-element.ts
    this.userId = this.auth.getUser().uid;
    this.listingProvider.checkUnreadThreads(this.listing.id).subscribe(threads => {
          threads.forEach(thread => {
            if (thread[this.userId].unread) { // <-Line 34 is here
              this.unread = true;
            }
          })
        })

    //listing-provider
      checkUnreadThreads(listingId) {
        return this.afs.collection(`listings/${listingId}/threads`)
          .snapshotChanges()
          .map(actions => {
            return actions.map(action => {
              const id = action.payload.doc.id;
              const data = action.payload.doc.data();
              return { id, ...data }
            });
          })
      }

    //listing-element.html
    <notification-badge *ngIf="userId === listingUserId && page.activity === true && unread"></notification-badge>
```

This is all the information I thought was pertinent, but if anyone needs more information, I'm more than happy to provide whatever I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether thread exist for the user before trying to access unthread property. Please let me know if you still face that issue

```
if (thread[this.userId] && thread[this.userId].unread) { 
              this.unread = true;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, while the example itself didn't work, it did give me the idea to try wrapping it in another if statement, but with only `thread[this.userId]` as the condition, rather than `thread[this.userId].unread`, and it stopped giving me the error!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
      (auth) => {
        if (auth != null) {
            this.listingProvider.checkUnreadThreads(this.listing.id).subscribe(threads 
               => {
              threads.forEach(thread => {
                if (thread[auth.uid].unread) { // <-Line 34 is here
                  this.unread = true;
                }
              })
            })
          })
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

`return { id, ...data }` will concat the id and all data fields in to one.

now your `thread` look like this

```
id:....,
unread:....,
fieldx:....,
fieldy:..... etc
```

try this code

```
this.userId = this.auth.getUser().uid;
this.listingProvider.checkUnreadThreads(this.listing.id).subscribe(threads => {
      threads.forEach(thread => {
        if (thread.id == this.userId && thread.unread) { 
          this.unread = true;
        }
      })
    })
```